# Synchronizing audio with video based on lip movement

Tags: windows, video-editing

I am looking for a program that can synchronize audio with video based on lip movement. (i.e. [Audio to video synchronization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_to_video_synchronization), a.k.a. audio video sync, audio/video sync, AV-sync, lip sync, or by the lack of it: lip sync error, lip-flap). In other words, the program takes as input an audio track and a video file with no audio track, and the program output a video file with an audio track that is synchronized with the video.

It should work on Microsoft Windows. Ideally, gratis. I am fine with any required input format for the audio and video. Any output format is good too.

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.